# Why are there no navigation points when using \printglossary in LaTeX beamer?

Tags: beamer, glossaries, acronyms

I want to include `acronyms` in my `beamer`. It works pretty well except that there are no navigation points under `ACRONYMS` unlike the others.

In the `MWE` below, I have commented `\section{ACRONYMS}` to prevent it from appearing twice in the navigation pane because it automatically appears when `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist,title=ACRONYMS]`. However, no navigation points appear under it.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{eth}{ETH}{Eidgenössische Technische Hochschule Zürich}
\makeglossaries
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=14mm,text margin right=14mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{ON GENERAL RELATIVITY}

\author{John Doe\inst{1}}

\institute[\acrfull{eth}]
{
  \inst{1}%
  {PhD Candidate at the Department of Physics\\
  \acrfull{eth}}}

\date{\today}

\subject{General relativity}

\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\logo{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    }\hskip-.1cm%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{OUTLINE}

\begin{frame}{OUTLINE}

\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}

INSERT INTRODUCTION.

\end{frame}

\section{THEORY}

\begin{frame}{THEORY}

INSERT THEORY.

\end{frame}

\section{RESULTS}

\begin{frame}{RESULTS}

INSERT RESULTS.

\end{frame}

\section{DISCUSSION}

\begin{frame}{DISCUSSION)}

INSERT DISCUSSION.

\end{frame}

\section{CONCLUSION}

\begin{frame}{CONCLUSION}

INSERT CONCLUSION.

\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

\nologo{
\begin{frame}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

INSERT BIBLIOGRAPHY

\end{frame}

% \section{ACRONYMS}

\begin{frame}{ACRONYMS}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist,title=ACRONYMS]

\end{frame}

\section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\begin{frame}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\centering{
\includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{30pt}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
}

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

- How can I make the navigation points appear under `ACRONYMS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave `\section{ACRONYMS}` to create the navigation point but add `\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}` (do nothing) to prevent the injection of the glossary title as another section.

Normally, the glossary title will appear (in the navigation bar) after running `makeglossaries` + `pdflatex` + `pdflatex`

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{eth}{ETH}{Eidgenössische Technische Hochschule Zürich}

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\makeglossaries
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=14mm,text margin right=14mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{ON GENERAL RELATIVITY}

\author{John Doe\inst{1}}

\institute[\acrfull{eth}]
{
    \inst{1}%
    {PhD Candidate at the Department of Physics\\
        \acrfull{eth}}}

\date{\today}

\subject{General relativity}

\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\logo{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
        \hfill%
        \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}%
    }\hskip-.1cm%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \section*{OUTLINE}
    
    \begin{frame}{OUTLINE}
        
        \tableofcontents
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{INTRODUCTION}
    
    \begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}
        
        INSERT INTRODUCTION.
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{THEORY}
    
    \begin{frame}{THEORY}
        
        INSERT THEORY.
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{RESULTS}
    
    \begin{frame}{RESULTS}
        
        INSERT RESULTS.
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{DISCUSSION}
    
    \begin{frame}{DISCUSSION}
        
        INSERT DISCUSSION.
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{CONCLUSION}
    
    \begin{frame}{CONCLUSION}
        
        INSERT CONCLUSION.
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \appendix
    
    \section{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    
    \nologo{
        \begin{frame}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
            
            INSERT BIBLIOGRAPHY
            
        \end{frame}
        
        \section{ACRONYMS}  % create a navigation point <<<<<
            
        \begin{frame}{ACRONYMS} 
                    
            \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist]  
                    
        \end{frame}
        
        \section{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
        
        \begin{frame}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
            
            \centering{
                \includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
                \hspace{30pt}
                \includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
            }
            
        \end{frame}
    }
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Simon Dispa! It did the trick -- now it all looks a lot more consistent and overall better.